# Tools needed for oil change on 2012 Honda Odyssey?

Tags: honda, oil-change, tools

What tools are needed to change the oil on a 2012 Honda Odyssey?

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? Are you asking if there is anything else you need?

Comment: In the future if you'd like to answer your own question Q&A style, build up a bit of rep (doesn't require much; 10 points maybe, I forget) and then choose the "Answer my own question" box when posting in the first place, or ask a quesiton then go back and answer it in the normal manner.

Answer (score 2):

Tools needed to change the oil on a 2012 Honda Odyssey would be:

1. oil filter wrench
2. oil drain washer
3. drain pan
4. car ramps
5. oil filter
6. OW-20 oil

Comment: presumably also some kind of wrench to remove the oil pan drain plug... tool sizes and oil quantity would be helpful additions.

Comment: This is the question posters original answer marked as CW. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I saw the CW designation. was hoping the OP would take another crack at it, or failing that, that someone from the community with the knowledge.

Comment: This is the same list of tools that are needed for an oil change on _any_ car (except the particular weight of oil).